# Signing a Windows application given a .SPC file?

Tags: windows, code-signing

My client wants to sign the application code. He gave me an .spc file for signing a .NET desktop application. How should I use it within the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

[http://ellisweb.net/2008/08/signing-code-using-pvk-and-spc-files/](http://ellisweb.net/2008/08/signing-code-using-pvk-and-spc-files)

Comment: That post assumes you have a PVK and SPC file but he states that he only has the SPC file.  The pvk2pfx tool seems to require the PVK file as its name implies.  You can import the SPC file into IE (if it isn't already in there) and follow @Roshil's instructions to get the PFX file.  That's how I converted my SPC file into a PFX file.

Answer (score 5):

Got a simple option.Install your spc file.
Go to Internet explorer=>tools=>content=> certificates.Then select your certificate and click export option.you can generate Pfx file.

then you can set this pfx file in the signing tab of the project properties from visual studio

Comment: You might need to import the SPC file into IE if you used Firefox to retrieve the original SPC like I did.  Technically I used Firefox to backup the cert to a p12 file then imported that into IE - I think you can import the SPC directly but I didn't do it that way so I'm not 100% sure.  Then you can export as @Roshil instructs.  If you find you need a strong naming file (.snk) for Visual Studio you can then use "sn -p mycert.pfx mycert.snk" from a VS command prompt.

Answer (score -2):

You sign the assembly before you send it to your customer. You can do this automatically in Visual Studio in the project settings.