# How to digitally sign my WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, code-signing, code-signing-certificate, assembly-signing

I have to digitally sign my WPF application created in visual studio 2012. goodday.com provide the   ".spc" file for this.But my visual studio requires pfx file format.How can I obtain certificate in PFX format?

Comment: See this similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286429/signing-a-windows-application-given-a-spc-file

Comment: but the the post has no answer.eventhough the link provides the explanation related to PVk files.But I have only spc file

Comment: You're rally lazy! Of course there is an answer, I saw it my self! Go here: http://ellisweb.net/2008/08/signing-code-using-pvk-and-spc-files/ Then read about how to convert your spc file to pfx using the tool included in .Net SDK pvk2pfx.exe Just read the command line help, it also accepts SPC files as input!

Comment: Got a simple option.Install your spc file.Go to Internet explorer=>tools=>content=> certificates.Then select your certificate and click export option.you can generate Pfx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a simple option.Install your spc file.Go to Internet explorer=>tools=>content=> certificates.Then select your certificate and click export option.you can generate Pfx file

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2019, Your are able to do the following:

1-Create a .NET Standard Class Library in Visual Studio.

2-Right-click on the project and go to properties

3-Click on the “Signing” tab

4-Check the “Sign the assembly” checkbox

5-Use the drop-down list to select an existing SNK, or create a new one. The file type is .pfs

6-If you create a new .pfs, it is critical to creat a strong password. Use a trusted password manager to generate a long password and store it.

For More info:
https://christianfindlay.com/2020/01/24/net-how-to-sign-an-assembly-in-visual-studio-2019/